# Should I use the past simple here?

Tags: continuous

I'm trying to write a paragraph in present continuous tense. Are these sentences correct?

Should I use the past simple in *stop working*?

> The bell is ringing. We stop working. We are very happy because we made a lot of beautiful products in Art class.

Comment: Aside from the question, remember it should be "Are these sentences correct?". There is no reason you shouldn't say *we are stopping work*, if you want to.

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se] for help with learning English.